# Detecting irregularities in binary sequence

Tags: r

In my dataset, each person has 11 answers to questions. The answers are stored with 0s (wrong) and 1s (right). So, I need to detect switching points from 0s to 1s. So, possible cases:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaSgi.jpg)

id 1 2 3 4 are regular responses because they either have one switching point or none.

id 5 and 6 are irregular responses because they have two switching points.

So, I need to have a column (consistent) and mark regular (one switching point or none) and irregular (multiple switching points) rows.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you dataset is a data.frame, you can use the abs of the diff of each row to identify switched. Then sum the number of switches to get the Consistent column

```
DF$Consistent <- apply(DF, 1, function(x) as.numeric(sum(abs(diff(x))) <= 1))
```

## data:

```
DF <- as.data.frame(rbind(c(0,0,0,1,1), c(1,1,0,0,0), c(1,1,1,1,1), c(0,0,0,0,0), c(1,0,1,0,0), c(0,0,0,1,0)))
```

Comment: Or you can use rle : `apply(DF,1,function(x)length(rle(x)$values) <= 2)`